# Problems with reading a file

Tags: c++

I turned in a homework assignment with what I believe is a read file error. I don't want to post all my code for the assignment for obvious reasons. We are on spring break and I MIGHT get feedback from my professor in a couple of weeks. I always seem to struggle with reading files so I'd like to get stuff figured out while I have time this week.

The gist of the assignment is to create a simple person object that has an STL set container containing  a string "gift" and a string containing a name as data members. Then, have a set of those objects. The first aspect of the program is to read a file with the following format, where the first word on the line is always a name and what is between the quotes is the gift idea:

```
Tom     "iphone"
Bill    "guitar"
Bill    "pencils"
Steve   "speaker"
Mary    "tennis racket"
Jenny   "golf balls"
John    "printer"
Bill    "books"
Mary    "books"
```

When printing to the screen, the format should be:

```
Bill    books, guitar, pencils
Jenny   golf balls
John    printer
Mary    books, tennis racket
Steve   speaker
Tom     iphone
```

In visual studio, everything is fine. But, when I compile and run with gcc the output looks like:

```
, pencilsooks
Jenny   golf balls
John    printer
Mary    books, tennis racket
Steve   speaker
Tom     iphone
```

After a few days off and looking at my readfile function, I noticed a few things that are wonky and it is not a well written function. That said, in VS when I debug, everything seems to work. When I connect to the linux server at school to test on gcc, things go wrong but I don't know how to debug in linux like I do in VS (something I need to learn).

Anyway, here is my readfile function:

```
//library facilities used: fstream, assert
//Postcondition: set of person objects have been created from file
void read_file(const char* file_name, set<person> &list)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(file_name);
    assert(infile);
    while( infile.good() )
    {
        string tmp_name; //stores name from file
        string tmp_gift; //stores gift from file
        person p_tmp;     //to be added to person_list
        set<person>::iterator people_iter; 

        infile >> tmp_name;//get 1st name in file

        //check to see if it's in the set of people
        if( in_list(tmp_name, list) )
        {
            getline(infile, tmp_gift, '\n'); //get the gift
            strip_punct(tmp_gift);
            add_to_existing(tmp_name, tmp_gift, list);
        }
        else //name is not in list
        {
            p_tmp.set_name(tmp_name);//set the name
            getline(infile, tmp_gift, '\n'); //get the gift
            strip_punct(tmp_gift);// get rid of quotes and other puncts
            p_tmp.insert_gift(tmp_gift);  //insert gift string into set of gifts for that person
            people_iter = list.begin();//add person to list of people
            list.insert(people_iter, p_tmp);    
        }//end else

    }// end while( infile.good() )

    infile.close();

}//end read_file
```

Comment: The problem will be to do with attempting to read from a text file that you created on Windows. They have newlines like `\r\n` and that carriage return character is ending up in the string for `guitar\r`.

Comment: I thought about that, too. I opened the file in vi and it looked OK. I'll test again and create the file in vi and get back to you. FWIW, I haven't had any issues like this before with data files created in VS or notepad++.

Comment: You are right! Interestingly, if I open the original file in vi, delete (by backspacing) the contents and then type in the data, the carriage return still persists. I had to create a new file in vi to solve the problem. I'm pretty sure the professor uses his own data file to grade, so I think I'm OK.